# overriding userAdmin by roles

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am developing a backend using [SonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) and I want to manage users by listing them by roles, for example a list of admin and a list of simple user.

I overrode the user admin class (AdministrateurAdmin and SimpleuserAdmin) like this:

```
<?php

namespace Myproject\BackendBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;

class AdministrateurAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin
{
    // ...
}
```

I want to show just the administrators by role **ROLE_ADMIN**.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this function :

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
  $query = parent::createQuery($context);
  $query->andWhere(
      $query->expr()->in($query->getRootAliases()[0] . '.roles', ':my_param')
  );
  $query->setParameter('my_param', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
  return $query;
}
```